# How can we skip a record while looping through an array in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

**Background:**

Iam building a ReactJS application. Backend REST service gives me JSON payload

```
this.state.payload =  [ { age:21, male: 'true' } , { age:31, male: 'false' } ];
```

And I have the following code to display this payload in the page.

```
      <div>
        {this.state.payload  && this.state.payload.map( (row, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <div> {row.age}</div>
            <div> {row.male}</div>
          </div> ))
         }
      </div>
```

**Issue:**

At the moment , I am displaying all the records in the payload in the screen.

I am not sure how i can skip records at the render time based on a condition.
(for e.g skip a record if the age is less than 25 ...don't display it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
  <div>
    {this.state.payload && this.state.payload
      .filter(row => row.age >= 25)
      .map((row, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <div> {row.age}</div>
          <div> {row.male}</div>
        </div>)
      ))}
  </div>
```

Thanks to @Curious13 for bringing up the server/client issue in the comments.  The other way to handle this, of course, is have the server ship the information pre-filtered (i.e. do the filtering on the server-side).  You would certainly want to do that if there were sensitivity concerns (i.e., the user wasn't supposed to even be aware of people under 25...and anyone who knows how to access the console can see that, even if you're not rendering it to the screen).  However, if the filtering is dynamic and/or we're not talking about a lot of data, it's fine to do it on the front-end with Array#filter.

Comment: Wouldn't you normally handle what you want displayed from your fetch inside the model itself and then fetch the record that you wanted? Instead of writing your model and filtering it on the client side?

Comment: Depends on the situation, @Curious13, but it's a good point.  If it's sensitive information (i.e. users that you aren't authorized to see or whatever), then that's an iron-clad reason to do it on the server side.  If it's a relatively few number of things that need to be filtered out, or its dynamic, there's little harm in it.

Comment: Okay. thank you for the clarification I wasn't too sure myself that's why I asked. I normally see guides online filtering out the information first in the model and then fetching the information to display the record in the view.

Comment: In my specific scenario, the backend rest operation  there for a while and was always returning a larger dataset. But a new equirement has arrived now and have to show a smaller subset of the data coming from REST service.  And it is not practical to create another REST operation for this minor change